# Add entries to OpenFire user's roster with PHP

Tags: php, openfire

I'm working on an OpenFire's client which requires being able to add entries to a user's Roster. The client is developed in PHP.

I've been looking into the OpenFire's database schema documentation, and tried implementing this by adding entries to the `ofRoster` table. This doesn't seem to be enough to achieve what I need. I have two questions:

1. Do you know which tables I should look into to "emulate" what the admin console does for adding an entry to a user's Roster?
2. Do you know of a better method for managing the Roster using PHP?

Answer (score 1):

The ofRoster table should be the only table you need to modify. [This Link](http://community.igniterealtime.org/docs/DOC-1674) should explain the meanings of the sub, ask, and recv columns. I have found that modifying the database directly doesn't seem to immediately reflect the new roster addition though. Good luck.

Edit 1: Be careful manipulating the roster tables--Openfire caches rosters for performance, so an update to the table will not be reflected immediately unless you force Openfire to clear its cache. The only way I currently know how to do this is by (and this is really bad if you intend Openfire to scale well) eliminating the roster cache.

This can be done by setting two properties (Server Manager > System Properties) in Openfire as such:

cache.username2roster.maxLifetime = 0
cache.username2roster.size = 0

Comment: Hi I can't find these two option can you help me? And is there any other way around?